# Box.com Content API: Add Collaboration

Tags: box-api

When using Box.Com APi, Add Collaboration method (https://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations-add-a-collaboration) there's a parameter that states that its type is object (the accessible_by parameter). This is an example of something that is actually all over the documentation.

Reading the documentation, seems to me that these are objects in mini format, but they don't state the type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the object format for the accessible_by parameter used in the Create Collaboration endpoint:

```
"accessible_by": { "id": "USER_ID", "type": "user" }
```